# Different Nmap results on MacOS and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nmap

I did a *Nmap* scan with this command:

```
nmap -sn -n --scan-delay 1s <ip range> -oG -
```

In *Ubuntu 16.04*, with *Nmap 7.01*, I'm getting different results from each scan.

In *MacOS X 10.13.3*, with *Nmap 7.60*, the result is the same every time.

The results that I am getting are a list of IP addresses. I use awk in my command to obtain this list of IPs, but that is not the problem and for that reason, I didn't write this part of the command in this post.

The scan is a internal network scan via VPN. In the case of *Ubuntu*, this conection is realized via Ethernet and *MacOS* is stablishing the conexión via 3G and, in other tryings, Wifi, in the same network where the Ethernet is connected.

The *Ubuntu* machine is a virtual machine, *VmWare NAT*, installed on *Windows 10*.

**Extra Test**

I tested with *Kali Linux 2018* and *Nmap 7.60*, creating no-sudo user and using it, and happened the same.

Why is it happening?

Comment: There is so much more inforamtion you will need to provide. Are they both connected in the same manner (wireless or physical) are they connected to the same switch (ACLs in place?), do they have the same IP scheme AKA are they on the same subnet (ACLs in place?) etc etc. Look at the network configuration on each of them and see if there is any differences that would limit one device and not the other.

Comment: What hypervisor are you using for the Ubuntu VM? Are you using bridged networking or NAT? For example, VirtualBox's NAT solution causes problems for Nmap scans.

Comment: 'different results' whothewhatnow?  Different ports found open?  Ports found closed versus filtered?  Fangs?  And how to the Ubuntu results compare to the MacOS results? Versions of nmap found on both?

Comment: The post has been udpated

Comment: Could it be that NAT network of vmWare is crafting the packets? Because I am receiving packets with the TTL 128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem is the *NAT* network. Analysing the network with *Wireshark*, I saw that the *TTL* number was 128. This is because in the *NAT* network recive the packets and recreate them. This cause problems on *Nmap* analysis. So, the solution is use a *Bridge* connection on *vmWare* or use *Nmap* on native OS.